# Angular Material Date Picker isn't using the specified Custom Date Format

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

I can't seem to get Material Datepicker to accept the format I'm giving it. I want to format the date as YYYY-MM-DD, but it insists on using M/D/YYYY.

Below is a stack-blitz where I'm reproducing the issue. Additionally, it's putting the previous date selected, at the bottom of the HTML page seemingly unsolicited.

Image of the Stackblitz below:
[image: Example of Date Issue]

I am customizing it as indicated by many different tutorials and documentation:

```
export const MY_DATE_FORMATS = {
    parse: {
      dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    },
    display: {
      dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
      monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
      dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
      monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY'
    },
  };
```

I am including it in my module.ts file:

```
providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_DATE_FORMATS}
  ]
```

I also tried changing out MatNativeDateModule with NativeDateModule:

```
imports:      [ 
BrowserModule, 
FormsModule,
MatDatepickerModule,  
NativeDateModule,    
BrowserAnimationsModule],
```

Below is my Stackblitz URL reproducing the issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bfjsid?file=src/app/app.module.ts

In this example, if I select a date, it's putting it in M/D/YYYY in the Input Box. Additionally it's putting the previous value at the bottom of the page, even though I don't have anything referencing it.

I have also tried to make sure the date format class was being used, by messing it up intentionally, and material complained as I would have hoped.

Can someone please take a look?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Will this work for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-date-5srxwu?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @Yiping WOW That's it!!!

Comment: @DanChase Is there a workaround for the parse property to be the same as NativeDateAdapter? if say, i type in 10/4/2023 it will output it as 2010-04-20 instead of 2023-10-04

Comment: @chitgoks Sorry I barely got to this point without the help above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing missing from your code is injection of MomentDateAdapter as a provider in your module.

```
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]
    },
```

The type of values that the datepicker expects depends on the type of DateAdapter provided. Read more about it here https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview under section "Setting the selected date" and you can decide on date implementation and date format settings based on this https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings.

The docs have it. :)

Comment: I think what throws me is the Moment part, since they support Native. Without getting into a tangent on Moment, I'm wondering if I need to just dogmatically use moment because that's the only thing that actually works, or if I can get Native to work - There doesn't seem to be a MAT_NATIVE_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly - you don't want to use Moment and you don't need to. But you will have to provide your custom adapter implementation. I have just made some changes and created a custom adapter which will parse the date in the format that you have mentioned. Find it here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t9chuc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-adapter.ts. And removed the usage of MomentDateAdapter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add Date Adapter in providers for the format to work.
Install dependency `@angular/material-moment-adapter`

```
import { MomentDateAdapter, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
{
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]
}
```

STackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w1pdob?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

### ISSUE 1: Unable to format Date as YYYY-MM-DD

### SOLUTION:

*You need `Angular Material Moment Adapter` to format date in datepicker.*

**Step 1:**

```
npm install @angular/material-moment-adapter
```

**Step 2:**

1. Add NativeDateModule in imports
2. Add MomentDateAdapter in providers

> app.module.ts

```
import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE, NativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    MatDatepickerModule,
    NativeDateModule,
  ],
  declarations: [...],
  bootstrap: [...],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]
    },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_DATE_FORMATS }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

---

### ISSUE 2: Previously selected value was shown in bottom of the page

### SOLUTION:

*You may add this CSS styling rule in global css to hide `.cdk-visually-hidden` element if not needed.*

```
.cdk-visually-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

[Sample project in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qmopr8)

Comment: Thanks Yong, is the way I did it just faulty? I was surprised the component completely ignored MY_DATE_FORMATS, but then I've never used it until now, and so many docs said to do it that way, obviously to no avail.

Comment: Hi, from your source code you are missing the `@angular/material-moment-adapter` and its related imports & providers in `app.module.ts`. Once you had completed the steps mentioned, you will able to see the datepicker is formatted. You may refer to this [docs](https://v11.material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#watching-the-views-for-changes-on-selected-years-and-months).